# Prove that $\,c\ge a+b$.

Tags: geometry

> In a cyclic quadrilateral $\,ABCD,\:\left\lVert AB\right\rVert = a,\,\left\lVert BC\right\rVert = b,\,\left\lVert CD\right\rVert = c,\,$ also angle $\,\measuredangle\, ABC=120°$ and $\,\measuredangle\, ABD=30°$. Prove that 
>   $c\ge a+b$.

I constructed the diagram and found that $\,\triangle\, ABC\,$ and $\,\triangle\, ADC\,$ are right triangles. Using cosine rule and Pythagoras theorem simultaneously I found 
$\,c^2=a^2+b^2-\sqrt{3}\,ab+\left\lVert AD\right\rVert ^2.\,$
Enough to show, $\,\left\lVert AD\right\rVert^2 \ge \left[\sqrt{3}+2\right]ab$.
But I can't prove this. Somebody please complete this or give me some another ideas.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly clear that the question has a typo, and that $CD = c$ was intended, rather than $CA = c$.

With that correction, the specified inequality can be proved as follows . . .

Since $\angle ABD = 30^\circ$, we get $\angle CBD = 120^\circ - 30^\circ = 90^\circ$.

Since $\angle CBD = 90^\circ$, it follows that chord $CD$ is a diameter, which implies $\angle CAD = 90^\circ$.

Since angles $ABD$ and $ACD$ are both inscribed in minor arc $AD$, it follows that $\angle ACD = 30^\circ$.

Then $\Delta CDA$ is a $30$-$60$-$90$ right triangle, hence, letting $e=AC$, we have $e = {\small{{\displaystyle{\frac{c}{2}}}}}\sqrt{3}$.

By the law of cosines,
\begin{align*}
e^2 &= a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\,\cos(120^\circ)\\[3pt]
&=a^2 + b^2 -2ab\left(-{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)\\[3pt]
&=a^2 + b^2 + ab\\[3pt]
\end{align*}

Then

\begin{align*}
e^2 &= a^2 + b^2 + ab\\[3pt]
\implies\;\; \left({\small{{\displaystyle{\frac{c}{2}}}}}\sqrt{3}\right)^2 &=a^2 + b^2 + ab\\[3pt]
\implies\qquad\;\;\; 3c^2 &= 4a^2 + 4b^2 + 4ab\\[3pt]
&= (3a^2 + 6ab + 3b^2) +  (a^2 - 2ab + b^2)\\[3pt]
&= 3(a + b)^2 + (a-b)^2\\[3pt]
&\ge 3(a + b)^2\\[3pt]
\end{align*}

Thus, $3c^2 \ge 3(a+b)^2$, hence $c \ge a + b$, as was to be shown.